# What is the Final Table equivalent for Merge?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I'm trying to use merge into to insert only new records.  I would like to collect the IDs for new records that got inserted and also the IDs for duplicate records that get ignored.

Here's the create statement for the table:

```
drop table SSZ_ME_MIS.test_update_table;
create table ssz_me_mis.test_update_table (
    ID_col int not null generated always as identity, -- Primary Key
    val_col_1 int not null,
    val_col_2 varchar(255) not null,
    constraint pk_test_update_table primary key (ID_col),
    constraint uq_test_update_table unique (val_col_1, val_col_2)
);
```

and then, to populate some initial values:

```
insert into ssz_me_mis.test_update_table (val_col_1, val_col_2)
select *
from (values 
    (231, 'Value 1'),
    (481, 'Value 2'),
    (813, 'Value 3')
);
```

So, finally, I'd like to try to do this sort of insert:

```
select ID_col from final table (
    merge into ssz_me_mis.test_update_table t using (
        select *
        from (values 
            (231, 'Value 1'),
            (481, 'Value 2'),
            (513, 'Value 4')
        )
    ) as s (val_col_1, val_col_2)
    on
        t.val_col_1 = s.val_col_1
        and t.val_col_2 = s.val_col_2
    when not matched then 
        insert (val_col_1, val_col_2)
        values (s.val_col_1, s.val_col_2)
    else
        ignore
);
```

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Comment: Db2-LUW does not yet (at v11.1.3.3) support select from merge (although Db2 for Z/OS supports it since V9 or V10). Suggest either to use two statements (one merge, one select) or wrap in an sproc that returns the relevant result-set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will run on Db2 LUW (assuming you are using `ORGANIZE BY ROW` tables).

```
with s (val_col_1, val_col_2) AS  (values 
            (231, 'Value 1'),
            (481, 'Value 2'),
            (513, 'Value 4')
        )
, i as (select * from final table(
    INSERT INTO ssz_me_mis.test_update_table ( val_col_1 , val_col_2) 
     select * from s where not exists (select 1 from ssz_me_mis.test_update_table t
        where 
        t.val_col_1 = s.val_col_1
        and t.val_col_2 = s.val_col_2
        )
))
, u as (select count(*) as dummy from new table(
    update ssz_me_mis.test_update_table t
    set val_col_1 = (select val_col_1 from s where t.val_col_1 = s.val_col_1 and t.val_col_2 = s.val_col_2)
    ,   val_col_2 = (select val_col_2 from s where t.val_col_1 = s.val_col_1 and t.val_col_2 = s.val_col_2)
    where exists    (select val_col_2 from s where t.val_col_1 = s.val_col_1 and t.val_col_2 = s.val_col_2)
))
select ID_col from i, u
```

I included a branch for updates, but logically you need some non-key columns for that to make sense. Your example is just an INSERT in practice, so I was a bit confused why you were using `MERGE` at all.

Comment: I was using merge to insert non-duplicate records.  I suppose an alternative to that would be to do an `insert into foo select * from bar where not exists (select ...)`?  Unfortunately the tables I'm working with are all column-organized but at this point, it's more for academics that I'm trying to figure this out.

Comment: If you are using `ORGANIZE BY COLUMN` tables, and you want to use changed table references like `FINAL TABLE` then you are out of luck currently. You could raise a RFE if this feature is important to you. If you need to know the values of the `ID_COL` column you might just have to allocate the values yourself, e.g. with `INSERT INTO foo SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY val_col1, val_col2) + COALESCE( (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM foo), ... FROM bar ...`